# Importing error?

Tags: java, bouncycastle

What am I doing wrong?

```
% javac  -cp ./:./bcprov-jdk16-nosign-140.jar MyProjectFile.java
MyProjectFile.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CipherInputStream
location: package org.bouncycastle.crypto.io
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.io.CipherInputStream;
                                 ^
```

I'm importing it like this:

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.io.CipherInputStream;
```

Is something wrong with the `.jar` file?

Comment: Geesh.... since when did SO becomes so lame?  I can't be slightly colorful with my language without getting whittled down to a twig?  Whatever.

Comment: Dear reviewers,
Instead of editing my question 30 seconds after I ask it maybe it would be nice to add a comment or send me a message asking me to refactor it.  Then I might go ahead and change it.  But, seriously, rewriting my question within only a few minutes of it being posted?? Wow, SO is suddenly not cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  I had a bad bouncycastle jar.  I deleted my bcprov-jdk16-nosign-140.jar file and grabbed the latest: bcprov-jdk15on-148.jar from their website.